# Getting error while installing Zoho Catalyst CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, catalystbyzoho, catalystserverless, zohocatalyst

I have tried to install Zoho Catalyst CLI in my local machine. At that time I am facing the below error

PS D:\Catalyst> npm install -g zcatalyst-cli
pm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade to version 7 or higher. Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problen tic. See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
hpm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https: //github.com/request/request/issues/3142
changed 353 packages in 14s
52 packages are looking for funding run "nom fund for details

[Terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oeVS.png)

Tried installing it again still facing the same error

Comment: Please post the error as a text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore all the warning messages while installing the Zoho Catalyst CLI. You can check whether the Catalyst CLI has been properly installed in your local machine by running the command `catalyst -v`. On running this command, the terminal should display the CLI version which has been installed.  As per [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zcatalyst-cli), their latest version is 1.16.2.